# What is the type of visa for the EEA Family Permit in a visa centre?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I am an EEA citizen, working in the UK, and my wife will apply to a EEA Family Permit to join me. I understand that it is categorized as a non-settlement visa, in the official website, but the visa centre doing the interview requires a subscription, and their categories differ.

Which would apply to the EEA Family Permit?

I hesitate mostly between the Family Visitor < 6 months, and Settlement (See below)

Here are the categories on the visa centre website:

- Settlement

> Settling means you can stay in the UK without any time restrictions.
> You can apply, if your situation is one of the following (if you have
> a visa as the dependant of someone else, select their visa):
>
> - You are the family member or partner of a British citizen;
> - **You are the family member or partner of someone who has settled in the UK;**
> - You have a visitor visa;
> - You have a study visa;
> - You have a work visa;
> - You have a UK Ancestry visa;
> - You have a Retired Person visa;
> - You have been settled in the UK before;
> - You have Discretionary Leave;
> - You are in or have been in HM Forces;
> - You are on the 10-year Private Life route;
> - You have been in the UK legally for 10 years (Long Residence).

- Family Visitor < 6 months:

> You can apply for a Standard Visitor visa if you want to visit the UK:
>
> - for leisure, eg on holiday or to see your family and friends;
> - for business, or to take part in sports or creative events;
> - for another reason, eg to receive private medical treatment.
>   The Standard Visitor visa has replaced the Family Visitor visa.

- Family Visitor > 6 months:

> If you are planning on coming to the UK to visit members of your family.

- Other non settlement:

> If you are invited to come to the UK due to your particular skills or
> expertise. You may apply to come to the UK for up to 1 month without
> the need to be sponsored under the points-based system. This category
> is for visiting examiners or assessors; lecturers; overseas designated
> pilot examiners; qualified lawyers; and professional artists,
> entertainers, and sportspersons.

- Visitor < 6 months

> If you are wanting to come and do business in the UK for a short time.
> This includes academic visitors, visiting professors, overseas news
> media representatives and film crews on location.

- Visitor > 6 months

> If you are planning to come to the UK as a tourist or to visit friends
> for a period of less than 6 months.

The remaining categories are Tier 1, 2, 3, 4, Student and Transit. I doubt those apply to my wife (she's not a student, and the UK would be her "final stop")

edit: The visa centre website is the following: uk.tlscontact.com/ru/ROV/index.php
I believe it requires to register before selecting the type of visa applied. That is why I copied/pasted the types in the question

Comment: What website are you using? On https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk, you select "reason for visit" = "other" and then "visa type" = "EEA/Swiss family member".

Comment: My answer was converted to a comment, which is fine, but the comment replying to my answer was deleted.  It said: This is the website of the visa centre: https://uk.tlscontact.com/ru/ROV/index.php

Answer (score 3):

You are asking where the EEA family permit fits in to the UK visa regime.  It doesn't.  You can use it to visit or to settle, the choice is yours.

To apply for a family permit, you should create an account at the UK visa portal, [Visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome).  Once you have created an account, the site uses 'wizard' software to guide you through the process.  [Phoog](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/2440/phoog) (to whom thanks) has pointed out that the initial pages contain some drop down selections, follow phoog's advice.  Once you have entered that selection the software will know what to do after that.

Here's a screen shot of the application where you specify your  visa type...

[image]

Important: your other option is to apply as a family visitor; this option lets you visit for up to 6 months, but does not lead to settlement. You would be expected to leave before this type of visa expires.  To apply as a family visitor, you would fill out the application like this...

[image]

Both of these options are available to you and you can select either depending upon your ultimate objectives.

Comment: My question is about a visa centre website, not the UK official website. I edited my question to add the details.

Comment: You should be using the 'official' web site.

Comment: The visa centre website enables us to track the application progress. Now, I agree, the application itself has to be done through the official website.

Comment: You have the wrong end of the stick.  Once you complete the application you will be sent to the page where you can select tracking options.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, the visa application worked, and to register on the visa centre website, we used the type **Family Visitor < 6 months**